# Typescript filter an array using filter()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the list of convention below, i want to filter this list by specialty, ie when i enter 15 it return the conventions with id 1 and 2

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "typeActivities": [
      {
        "id"=11,
        "specialitiesId": [10, 15]
      }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "typeActivities": [
      {
        "id"=22,
        "specialitiesId": [10]
      },
      {
        "id"=222,
        "specialitiesId": [15]
      }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "typeActivities": [
      {
        "id"=33,
        "specialitiesId": [12]
      }
   ]
 }
]
```

i tried with this function but is return nothing

```
let input: number = 15;
let convention: Convention[];
convention = this.conventions.filter(convention => {
    let typeActivities: TypeActivity[] = convention.typeActivities.filter(typeActivitiy => {
        if (typeActivitiy.specialitiesId) {
            return input == typeActivitiy.specialitiesId.find(id => id == input);
        }
    });
    //console.log(convention.typeActivities.map(i => i.id).filter(item => typeActivities.map(i => i.id).indexOf(item) >= 0));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is really useful for things like this:

```
let input: number = 15;
let convention: Convention[];
convention = this.conventions.filter(convention =>
    convention.typeActivities.some(activity =>
        activity.specialitiesId.some(e => e == input)
    )
);
```

`convention.typeActivities.some(...)` will call its predicate with each entry until it runs out (`some` returns `false`) or the predicate returns a truthy value (`some` returns `true`); the same with `activity.specialitiesId.some(...)`.

Live JavaScript example:

```js
const example = {
    conventions: [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "typeActivities": [
              {
                 "id": 11,
                 "specialitiesId": [10, 15]
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "typeActivities": [
              {
                  "id": 22,
                  "specialitiesId": [10]
              },
              {
                  "id": 222,
                  "specialitiesId": [15]
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "id": 3,
          "typeActivities": [
               {
                   "id": 33,
                   "specialitiesId": [12]
               }
          ]
      }
    ],
    find(input) {
      let convention;
      convention = this.conventions.filter(convention =>
        convention.typeActivities.some(activity =>
          activity.specialitiesId.some(e => e == input)
        )
      );
      return convention;
    }
};
console.log(example.find(15));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```